# German Umlaut characters in R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

How can I display non-English characters in R-markdown?  In an otherwise English document, I would like to render a single **'u' with two dots (an 'umlaut') on top of it.**  It is the correct spelling for **'u'** in the name **'Muller.'**

Comment: Thanks, I just tried `M\"uller` and `M \"u ller` , and `\"u` on its own line, and unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26821326/how-can-i-write-special-characters-in-rmarkdown-latex-documents

Comment: It all works if you "just" enter the proper Unicode character. See the answer I just added.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [standard HTML code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) for this. 
For example, the German letter ä can be displayed by placing the corresponding vowel after an ampersand sign, followed by `uml;`, i.e., `&auml;`.

Here's an example of a .Rmd file:

```
---
title: "Umlauts with Rmarkdown"
output: html_document
---

## This is a sentence with many umlaut characters:

Herr M&uuml;ller sagt: "&Uuml;ber den Wolken k&ouml;nnen Sonnenunterg&auml;nge 
besonders sch&ouml;n sein."
```

[image]

Comment: That seems suboptimal. I think you want encoding.

Comment: Since v1 of RStudio you can insert unicode characters in source files, even on Windows.

Answer (score 15):

We can do one better than in @RHertel answer. While the *explicit* use of HTML markup works, it *may restrict* us to HTML output -- which is uncool.

Checking with the RStudio documentation you see that UTF-8 is already the default (though I did an extra 'File -> Save with Encoding' which just showed that it already was at UTF-8). Hence it is just a matter of entering proper unicode characters. Below is a little variation on the standard file RStudio creates:

```
---
title: "Encoding Demo"
author: "Dirk Eddelbüttel"
date: "2/27/2016"
output: html_document
---

## R Markdown

Herr Müller sagt: "Über den Wolken können Sonnenuntergänge besonders schön sein."
```

which results in the following HTML:

[image]

Comment: Any experience with how the german 'Umlaute' can be pushed to the Rmarkdown if the text (ie the word containing the Umlaut) is part of a text in a data.frame or more precisely a tibble row/cell?