# German Umlaute in RMarkdown and rticle

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, diacritics

I create a new document using the R Markdown Template American Economic Association journals. 
However, when knitting the whole document, my German Umlaute (such as ä, ü, Ö) are not displayed at all.

Reproducible example:

```
---
title: "Der Effekt von Ü auf Ö and ä"
short: "ä ü ö"
journal: "AER" # AER, AEJ, PP, JEL
month: "`r lubridate::month(Sys.time())`"
year: "`r lubridate::year(Sys.time())`"
vol: 1
issue: 1
jel:
  - A10
  - A11
keywords:
  - ö
author:
  - name: Öder Ügo
    firstname: Ö
    surname: Ügo
acknowledgements: |
  Acknowledgements
abstract: |
 ÖÄÜ
output: rticles::aea_article
---
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I write special characters in RMarkdown latex documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26821326/how-can-i-write-special-characters-in-rmarkdown-latex-documents)

Comment: @JanvanderLaan: No - not a duplicate, because this solution does not work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the resulting TeX file, you see the umlauts right there. The problem is just that by default LaTeX does not know how to deal with them. I see two possible solutions:

- Make use of XeLaTeX via

  ```
  output: 
    rticles::aea_article:
      latex_engine: xelatex
  ```
- Adjust the `template.tex` file to include `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in the preamble.

I would use the first approach. Either way you might have to post-process the resulting TeX file before submission: Replace all umlauts by the corresponding TeX commands (`\"{U}` etc.) and possbily remove the `\usepackage`.

In the future, this will work out of the box, since [LaTeX will use UTF-8 by default](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/24)!