# Can I type \LaTeX or other special symbols inside verbatim code in Rmarkdown?

Tags: latex, r-markdown, special-characters, symbols, code-formatting

I know I can use $$ to write `\LaTeX` in Rmarkdown documents like $\beta$. My goal is if this is possible inside verbatim code.

I would do `` `$\beta$` `` or `` `$\\beta$` ``, but both do not work.

In case it is not possible, is there some way to generate a greek letter inside verbatim code in Rmarkdown?

Following [How can I write special characters in RMarkdown latex documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26821326/how-can-i-write-special-characters-in-rmarkdown-latex-documents), I tried `` `&beta;` ``.

But it also does not work. What can I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in [TeX SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481748/can-i-type-latex-inside-inline-code-in-rmarkdown). Essentially, just copy and paste the corresponding symbol `β`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get [image] from:
`` `r paste0("$\\beta$ = ", mean(mtcars$mpg))` ``

For highlighting, add:

```
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{xcolor}
```

to your YAML header and wrap your R code chunk like so:

```
\colorbox{lightgray}{
`r paste0("$\\beta$ = ", mean(mtcars$mpg))`
}
```

Comment: I do not get what I want., since it is not highlighted like verbatim code.

Comment: In that case, I might suggest adding: `header-includes:
   - \usepackage{xcolor} and `\colorbox{lightgray}{
`r paste0("$\\beta$ = ", mean(mtcars$mpg))`
}`